# Putsftp is taking a wrong path in SFTP server in nifi

Tags: file, configuration, apache-nifi

I have a flow to fetch file from SFTP server, rename it and put it back to server in same location.

My flow:
Listsftp-> fetchsftp-> updateAttribute-> putsftp

My file location is in d drive, I have mentioned that location in remote path property of putsftp but it taking the path like
c:/users/myname/d:/file/location
And of course it is giving me error.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the expression you have used while renaming the file? Also add the source path and expected destination path details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SFTP processor only if you are using a server with Host - Port etc.
If you want to get some files from your disk (C:/ for example) you can use the **GETFILE** processor
an example of flow could be this:

1. **GETSFTP** with the property `Keep Source File` to `false`
2. **UpdateAttribute**
   new property -> filename -> new_file_test.example
3. **PUTSFTP**

you can use GETSFTP/GETFILE PUTSFTP/PUTFILE